# ui-select with single select (limit attribute is not working)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-select

Here is my code. I used angular UI-select. It is working great. But now, the requirement changed for the dropdown to be selected only once. I used limit attribute, but its not working.

```
<span id="oCountriesSpan" ng-class="{'has-error': noCountriesSelected()}">
                            <ui-select multiple limit="1" ng-model="countryModel.selectedCountries" ng-disabled="isReadOnly" theme="bootstrap">
                                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select ..." allow-clear="true">{{$item.name}}
                                </ui-select-match>
                                <ui-select-choices repeat="country.id as country in countryCodes | filter:$select.search">
                                    {{ country.name }}
                                </ui-select-choices>
                            </ui-select>
                        </span>
```

Comment: is there any other way to limit the select to just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit was introduced after 0.13 version. I was using 0.12

Answer (score 0):

**Use following code to clear selected option value**

**HTML Code**

```
<ui-select-match placeholder=”Enter table…”>
 <span>{{$select.selected.description || $select.search}}</span>
 <a class=”btn btn-xs btn-link pull-right” ng-click=”clear($event, $select)”><i class=”glyphicon glyphicon-remove”></i></a>
</ui-select-match>
```

**Controller action Code**

```
function clear($event, $select){ 
 //stops click event bubbling
 $event.stopPropagation(); 
 //to allow empty field, in order to force a selection remove the following line
 $select.selected = undefined;
 //reset search query
 $select.search = undefined;
 //focus and open dropdown
 $select.activate();
}
```